# Upload file with user id to database

Tags: php, laravel

Hi everyone I want to add a file, not an image. There are different types of files in laravel. With the file I need to upload the user id to the database but I don't know how to store it in controller, here are my scripts:

Controller.php:

```
public function uploaded(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

         $path = $request->image->store('storage/uploads','public');

        return back();
    }
```

upload.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['FileController@upload', $client->id, 'files' => 'true']]) !!}
                    {!!Form::file('image') !!}
                    {!!Form::submit('Upload File') !!}
                   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and web.php

```
Route::post('upload/{id}/', 'FileController@uploaded');
```

Can you explain me how to do it correctly?

Comment: The same way you would with an image. There is no difference as far as uploading is concerned

Comment: @RiggsFolly but how to upload it with user id?

Comment: Is it the id of the logged in user?

Comment: @RiggsFolly id is in link -> /upload/2

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `upload.blade.php` as

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['file.upload', $client->id, 'files' => 'true']]) !!}
    {!!Form::file('image') !!}
    {!!Form::submit('Upload File') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and your `web.php` to

```
Route::post('upload/{id}/', 'FileController@uploaded')->name('file.upload');
```

Comment: Why file.upload not only upload?

Comment: You can name your route as you want https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Comment: now i have problem here -> $path = $request->image->store('storage/uploads','public');
Call to a member function store() on string

Comment: You could try with `$request->file('image')->store('folder location');`

Answer (score 0):

I little confuse about your question. But I hope my answer can help you with your problem.

**First Answer:**

If you want to save the file in database I think you can save it with store the file path only in another table, we can call it `user_files` with this structure:

**user_files**

### | id | user_id | file |

| 1 | 2 | /home/name/file

And the relations between this table and clients table is oneToMany.

so in your Client.php will be have this method:

**Client.php**

```
public function files() {
    return $this->hasMany(File::class, 'user_id');
}
```

and your File.php will be have this method:

**File.php**

```php
public function client() {
    return $this()->belongsTo(Client::class, 'user_id');
}
```

After that, now we move in controller that handle upload method. We should save the file with associate the data from client.

```
public function uploaded(Request $request, $id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

    // If you need to upload file not only image, I think you should use $request->file() method;
    $file = $request->file('file');


    // And then we save the name use this method, maybe you want to save it with change the name and include the user_id
    $name = 'User' . '#' . $client->id . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    // It will make the file named 'User#2.doc'

    // After that we move the file in 'uploads' directory or other public directory you want.
    $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $name);

    $newFile = new File;
    $newFile->file = public_path('uploads') . '/' . $name;
    $newFile->client()->associate($client);
    $newFile->save();


    return back();
}
```

That if you want to save the file in database with user_id as identifier, and also you can access it as usual, like if you want to access the image file:

```
<img src="{{$newFile->file}}" />
```

---

**Second Answer**

But if you only want to save the file with the name of user_id you can use only the method in controller:

```
public function uploaded(Request $request, $id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

    // If you need to upload file not only image, I think you should use $request->file() method;
    $file = $request->file('file');


    // And then we save the name use this method, maybe you want to save it with change the name and include the user_id
    $name = 'User' . '#' . $client->id . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    // It will make the file named 'User#2.doc'

    // After that we move the file in 'uploads' directory or other public directory you want.
    $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $name);

    return back();
}
```

Comment: There is a problem - Call to a member function move() on null

Comment: Oh okay my bad, but let me help you :'D. First, set your form with add enctype properties. `{{ Form::open(['files' => true]) }}` try this

Comment: This will make `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" />` and in your input make sure the name of the input is `file` also :-D